# Google Visualization:how to make a simple bar chart in GWT

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

i am making my first chart in google visualization , 
trying to make a simple bar chart

I got this from the example :

```
        VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
        Options options = Options.create();
        options.setHeight(240);
        options.setTitle("Company Performance");
        options.setWidth(400);
        options.set3D(true);

        DataTable data = DataTable.create();
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Year");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses");
        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, "2004");


        VisualizationWidget<BarChart, BarChart.Options> widget = 
          BarChart.createWidget(data, options);
        BarChart viz = widget.getVisualization();
        Label status = new Label();
        viz.addSelectHandler(new SelectionDemo(viz, status));
        vp.add(status);
        vp.add(widget);
```

this line

```
                  VisualizationWidget<BarChart, BarChart.Options> widget = 
          BarChart.createWidget(data, options);
```

says

```
               VisualizationWidget cannot be resolved to a type
```

compilation error :

```
    [ERROR] Line 150:  VisualizationWidget cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Line 151:  The method createWidget(DataTable, PieChart.Options) is undefined for the type BarChart
  [ERROR] Line 154:  SelectionDemo cannot be resolved to a type
```

i'm not able to understand whats this VisualizationWidget, if you could guide me how to resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows that you might forget to add a dependency of Visualization jar in your project.
you could try to add the dependency by hand to the .gwt.xml file in your project:

```
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization'/>
```

Add below code in your **.html** file:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {'packages' : ["corechart"] });
    </script>
```

**Code**

```
@Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {


          VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
            final Options options = Options.create();
            options.setHeight(240);
            options.setTitle("Company Performance");
            options.setWidth(400);
            options.set3D(true);

             DataTable data = DataTable.create();
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Year");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses");
            data.addRows(4);
            data.setValue(0, 0, "2004");

            BarChart barChart=new BarChart(data, options);

            vp.add(barChart);
            RootPanel.get().add(vp);


            Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  Panel panel = RootPanel.get();

                  // Create a pie chart visualization.
                  BarChart pie = new BarChart(createTable(), options);
                  panel.add(pie);
                }
              };


              VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, BarChart.PACKAGE);

    }
      private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
            DataTable data = DataTable.create();
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
            data.addRows(2);
            data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
            data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
            data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
            data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
            return data;
          }
```

Comment: ok,Try to compile your project and Let me know what is the compilation error? I may help.

Comment: sorry, I don't have a sample code right now. wait if someone not help it out, I will add a sample code. you can also try with the sample link http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted

Comment: I just get an other code , on which i am getting this at run time     : Cannot read property 'visualization' of undefined , Any idea ..

Comment: I have edited working code. It will help you. it is generating two bar chart.

Comment: thanks for the code , I have simply pasted your code and also in my html file, but at this line : DataTable data = DataTable.create();i am getting error :   Cannot read property 'visualization' of undefined

Comment: this sample is working, might be some jar problem use this jar http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-visualization-1.0.2.zip&can=2&q= and again  check it.

Comment: yes, using the same jar , tried the same on firefox , there the error is 
$wnd.google is undefined    and in IE  error is 
 '$wnd.google.visualization' is null or not an object

Comment: I provided a html code that should be exist in your module html file.    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {'packages' : ["corechart"] });
 </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="stylegwt/stylegwt.nocache.js"></script>

Comment: solved , this need to be added in .html     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>. Thanks